# How can I answer the question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On Monday, it took Helen 3 hours to do a page of science
homework exercises. The next day she did the same number
of exercises in 2 hours. If her average rate on Monday was
p
exercises per hour, what was her average rate the next day, in
terms of
p
?

Comment: It has been asked many times: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130514203304AAZwoPV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avg rate of doing work (A.R.W) equals total work (T.W) divided by total time (T.T).
Thus her

$$ T.W = T.T \times A.R.W=3p. $$

On the next day her A.R.W becomes $3p/2$. Since total work is the same in the two days.

Comment: Please improve formating of your answer